# For all functions $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, there exists $\alpha$ s.t. $f'(\xi)=\alpha \xi$ for some $\xi \in [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while but I'm stuck; the problem asks me to show that for all differentiable functions $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ there exists a unique number $\alpha$ suct that for each one of these functions there exists $\xi \in [0,1]$ such that $f'(\xi) = \alpha \xi$,  $\xi$ could vary for different functions.

So far, I know that $\alpha \geq 1$ beacuse the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ is always greater or equal to $1$, also I tried to use the mean value theorem without any success.

Comment: Is the title wrong or did you mean $f(\xi)=\alpha \xi$ ?

Comment: yes, I forgot it, it was f'

Comment: It seems to me like there might be one too many quantifiers in the problem statement. $f$ is quantified twice?

Answer (score 3):

We take $\alpha=2$ ($\alpha$ does not depend of $f$). Let $g(x)=f(x)-\frac{\alpha}{2}x^2=f(x)-x^2$ for $x\in[0,1]$, then $g$ is differentiable and $g(0)=g(1)=0$. By Rolle's theorem, there exists $\xi\in [0,1]$ such that $g'(\xi)=0$, that is to say $f'(\xi)=2\xi=\alpha\xi$.

Comment: can you show $\alpha$ is unique?

Comment: I forgot this part of the question. If we restrain ourself to $\xi\in(0,1)$, we can take $f(x)=x^2$, there exists $\xi\in (0,1)$ such that $2\xi=\alpha\xi$ and $\alpha=2$ because $\xi\neq 0$. In the case $\xi\in [0,1]$, we have to find $f$ such that $f’(0)\neq 0$, maybe $f(x)=2^x-1$ works, I don’t have the time to think about it right now.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x) =f(x) -f(0)- (f(1)-f(0))x^2=f(x) - x^2$
$g$ satisfies conditions of Rolle's theorem on $[0,1]$, hence there exists a $\eta\in (0,1)$ such that, $g'(\eta) =f'(\eta) - 2(f(1)-f(0))\eta=0=f'(\eta)-2\eta$.Choose $\alpha=2. $

Comment: A single value of $\alpha$ is supposed to work for all functions. Your $\alpha$ depends on the function.

Comment: @JonathanZ supports MonicaC: While writing the answer, I missed the given info. that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ so I wrote the proof for any $f$ differentiable on $[0,1]$. However, if you use the given info. then clearly $\alpha =2$. I have updated the answer to avoid confusion. Instead of directly assuming $g(x) =f(x) - x^2$,I wrote that expression for $g$ hoping that the OP would understand how $g(x) $ was constructed.

Comment: Much clearer. Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC: You are welcome.